# UrlRewriting.net move to IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-6

On my ASP.NET site, I used UrlRewriting.net on win 2003, IIS6 (http://www.urlrewriting.net/), now server updated to win 2008 with IIS7 and it doesn't work, when try to open rewritten url, error says 404 Not Found.

How can I fix that or how to resolve that.

Appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the HttpModules definition in your web.config file from system.web to system.webServer

```
<system.web>
       <httpModules>
          <add name="UrlRewriteModule"type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
       </httpModules>
</system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UrlRewriteModule"type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    </modules>
 <system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you! I added but now it throws an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +38

Comment: From the web site forum, http://lyngtinh.blogspot.sg/2010/04/fixed-error-urlrewritingneturlrewrite.html